# On Solaris; find, append to a tar ball and compress question

Tags: solaris, tar, bzip2

Solaris 11

I want to find all files greater that 31 days, tar them and compress the tar file.

I'd like to do this on one line.  I'd rather use pbzip2 than gzip!!!

Here is what I tried as a prototype:

`find /tmp -mtime +31 -type f -name "arch*" -exec sh -c 'tar -czvPfE /tmp/old_files_$(date +%F).tar.gz $0' {} \;`

Problem with this is it creates a tar.gz for each file over-writing the file before it (I want all the files in only one tar ball).  The "r" doesn't work unless the tar exists.  And the "z" calls gzip not pbzip2

UPDATE:

`@DopeGhoti  Thank you.  First, my bad for not checking the man page for the "j" option.  However, this almost worked.
root@myhost:/tmp# find /tmp -mtime +31 -type f -name "arch*"| wc -l  =207
root@myhost:/tmp# find /tmp -mtime +31 -type f -name "arch*"| xargs tar -cjf /tmp/old_files_$(date +%F).tbz
root@myhost:/tmp# l|tail
-rw-------   1 root     root        1.6K Nov 30 15:59 old_files_2017-11-30.tbz
root@myhost:/tmp# bunzip2 old_files_2017-11-30.tbz
root@myhost:/tmp# tar tf old_files_2017-11-30.tar|wc -l  =15`

Comment: Yes, I could do this line by line in a script, but I was hoping to make an alias that I can run anytime I am under space pressure on the system.

Comment: `find [...] | xargs tar -cjf "/path/to/tarball-$(date +%F).tbz"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file names don't contain newline characters, POSIXly (except for `pbzip2` obviously), which takes the list of files to archive on stdin by default (and also writes the archive on stdout by default)

```
find /tmp -mtime +31 -type f -name "arch*" | pax -w | pbzip2 > file.tar.bz2
```

Or to use Solaris `tar` so you can keep your `P`/`E` options:

```
find /tmp -mtime +31 -type f -name "arch*" |
  tar cvPEf - -I /dev/stdin | pbzip2 > file.tar.bz2
```

`-I /dev/stdin` to take the file list from stdin, `f -` to output the archive on stdout, which is then compressed by `pbzip2` like with `pax`.

Comment: Mind explaining the mechanism behind these two?  "pax -w" and "tar cvPEf - -I /dev/stdin"   Just curious how this works...

Comment: @Marinaio, see edit.